# Passar parâmetros via jquery para a minha model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Sempre passei paramatros para minha controller assim:

```
url: '/Minha_Controller/Minha_Função',
....
```

Agora preciso passar parâmetros diretamente para a Minha Model e não sei como fazer. Tenho essa model: MontaArvoreAcao.cs.
Assim não dá certo, dá erro.

```
url: '/Minha_Model/Minha_Função',
.....
```

Como eu faço então?

Comment: Passar parâmetros direto pra model? Isso tá errado.

Comment: Ok, aceito a orientação.

Comment: Você quer colocar informação em seu model através de JQuery para que este chegue ao controller preenchido? É isso?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja preencher uma propriedade em seu model através de Jquery.

Se realmente for isto, você pode colocar um input Hidden na view representando seu model, e alterar o valor deste através de JQuery. Caso o elemento já exista (não sendo um hidden), apenas pegue o elemento HTML e altere seu valor. O MVC realiza o model binding para enviar o model para seu controller através do name dos elementos.

Por exemplo:

```
@model Meu.Model.FooModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
       @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.Atributo, new { id = "AtributoDoModel" })
       <input type="submit" val="Enviar" />
}

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#AtributoDoModel").val("NovoValorDoMeuAtributo");
        });
</script>
```

O código acima deve alterar a propriedade Atributo do model FooModel para o valor "NovoValorDoMeuAtributo", conforme script em JQuery.

Answer (score -2):

No seu método da controller você vai receber a sua model. Para que o valores da sua model seja preenchida corretamente na controller será necessário que na View você utilize os campos com o mesmo nome da model.
Ex.: campo Nome na model
Na view usar: